# Дружба SpringSecurity, Spring MVC и GWT

Tags: spring, gwt

Начал я писать веб-приложение, используя стандартный Spring Security, Spring MVC, Hibernate стэк технологий. Для клиентской части выбрал GWT, решил подружить его с DispatcherServlet и тут-то и началось самое интересное. Интегрировать решил, пользуясь философией этой [статьи](https://technophiliac.wordpress.com/2008/08/24/giving-gwt-a-spring-in-its-step/). На выходе имеем кастомный конфигуратор:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringForGwtConfig {
@Bean
public HandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    Map<String, Controller> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("/notes/notes.rpc", notesGwtController());
    simpleUrlHandlerMapping.setUrlMap(map);
    return simpleUrlHandlerMapping;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean gwtServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(notesGwtController(), "/notes/notes.rpc");
}

@Bean
public NotesGwtController notesGwtController() {
    NotesGwtController notesGwtController = new NotesGwtController();
    notesGwtController.setRemoteService(notesService());
    return notesGwtController;
}

@Bean
public NotesGwtService notesService() {
    return new NotesGwtServiceImpl();
}
}
```

Реализовал контроллер для перехвата обращений к notes/notes.rpc следующим образом:

```
public class NotesGwtController extends RemoteServiceServlet implements Controller, ServletContextAware {
private ServletContext servletContext;
private RemoteService remoteService;
private Class remoteServiceClass;

@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    super.doPost(request, response);
    return null;
}

@Override
public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {
    try {
        RPCRequest rpcRequest = RPC.decodeRequest(payload, this.remoteServiceClass);
        // delegate work to the spring injected service
        return RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(this.remoteService, rpcRequest.getMethod(), rpcRequest.getParameters());

    } catch (IncompatibleRemoteServiceException exception) {
        getServletContext()
                .log(
                        "An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.",
                        exception
                );
        return RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(null, exception);
    }
}

@Override
public ServletContext getServletContext() {
    return servletContext;
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
}

public void setRemoteService(RemoteService remoteService) {
    this.remoteService = remoteService;
    this.remoteServiceClass = this.remoteService.getClass();
}
}
```

Кроме него есть до банальности простой контроллер, который возвращает вьюху notes.html при запросе localhost:8080/notes/notes. Он возвращает, он молодец. Но при попытке связаться с сервером, используя RPC GWT, консоль в браузере выдает следующее:
**POST http://localhost:8080/notes/notes/notes.rpc 403 ()**

Я стал грешить на конфигуратор SpringSecurity и добавил в него последнюю строчку из листинга ниже:

```
http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/notes").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/notes/notes.rpc").anonymous()
```

Но это не помогло. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. И ещё - может существует лучший способ подружить эти две технологии? Может сделать полностью отдельный сервер на SptingMVC, а в клиентской части использовать чистое GWT с родным RPC?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `http.csrf().disable()` , может эта защита не пускает.

Comment: Вот ведь никогда бы не подумал, что она по дефолту включена, да ещё и может помешать, спасибо)